# Scroll to top of WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

How can you scroll to the top of a web broswer  control. The page I am loading has an iframe and the scroll bar is starting 20px down. It only happens in my application. I would like to auto scroll to the top.

Answer (score 2):

Quick search yields: `webBrowser1.Document.Window.ScrollTo(0, 200);`

Answer (score 1):

If what you mean is wanting to scroll the content of the iframe to the top, the following should help.

First you will need 2 things:

1. Add reference to **C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\Microsoft.mshtml.dll**
2. edit your `<iframe>` tag so that it has an id, eg: `id="something"`

Finally, the code:

```
HtmlElement ele = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("something");
mshtml.HTMLIFrameClass frame = ele.DomElement as mshtml.HTMLIFrameClass;
if (frame != null)
{
    mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass doc = frame.document as mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass;
    if (doc != null)
    {
        object i = 0;
        mshtml.HTMLWindow2Class win = doc.frames.item(ref i) as mshtml.HTMLWindow2Class;
        if(win != null)
            win.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
}
```